# HTML Directory Selector that maintains inner folders

Tags: javascript, php, html

What I have working is a directory selector in a form group, it properly submits and all 100+ files make it to the POST method. The problem is, the files in the 'Project Folder' are in 4 folders that must be maintained. Submitting the project folder puts the files in all 4 folders into one array of file objects. The code below is what I have.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="project_folder">Project Folder</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <input id="project_folder" name="project_folder[]" type="file"  webkitdirectory='' mozdirectory='' directory='' multiple=''
            class="form-control input-md" value="<?=Input::old('project_folder')?>">
  </div>
</div>
```

To reiterate: I need to modify this working directory selector to submit the form with the 4 inner folders maintained. I also have a version with 4 of these inputs where you select all 4 folders separately, which uploads the files in their 4 separate arrays (WHICH IS WHAT I NEED), but I need to get it down to one directory select because of human error issues that have come up. i.e Break the one selected directory up into its 4 inner directories. Any advice is appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself, did it all in JavaScript.

```
for(var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
    var file = files[x];
    var relativePath = file.webkitRelativePath;
    if(relativePath.includes('/xFolder/')) {
        formData.append('x_folder[]', file, file.name);
    } else if(relativePath.includes('/yFolder/')) {
        formData.append('y_folder[]', file, file.name);
    } else if(relativePath.includes('/zFolder/')) {
        formData.append('z_folder[]', file, file.name);
    } else if(relativePath.includes('/sourceFolder/')) {
        var re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
        var ext = re.exec(file.name);
        if(!foundSource && ext[0] === ".xlsx") {
            foundSource = true;
            formData.append('source_file', file, file.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Had to scrap using form submission because it disregards subfolders and just dumps all the files in; using FormData allowed me to group the files as needed. I changed the upload process to AJAX from the JS file. (folder names generalized for privacy reasons)